# How to script for a graceful program 'quit' as 'kill' leaves a mess behind

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

On PClinuxOS 2010 I use SMB4K to manage LAN shares. It works perfectly, unless I forget to quit SMB4K before shutting down the computer. If I forget, AND a mounted network share has gone offline, the shutdown procedure always hangs. Shutdown complains that it cannot unmount my Home directory as it is busy. This is obviously related to SMB4K (which mounts LAN shares within Home) as shutdown proceeds uneventfully when I have quitted SMB4K prior to shutdown. | have found that 'killing' SMB4K leaves LAN shares mounted, whereas 'quitting' leads to shares being unmounted before its process ends. My scripting knowledge is almost nil, but I'm wondering if a line within the /etc/rc.d/init.d/halt script might be the answer. If so, how can the halt script be told to 'quit' SMB4K instead of 'killing' it?

Answer (score 1):

`killall -s QUIT SMB4KProcessName...`

Comment: Alas, killall -s QUIT smb4k does nothing! I don't see why, because RedGrittyBrick's logic is sound and thanks for it.